# re-enabling the disable button after correcting the entered input

Tags: php, jquery

i am checking while entering the id wether the id is already exist in the database and if id exist then message displayed 'not available' ,it displays the message, but i want the button to be disable after displaying the message ,and when i clear the id and re-enter the new id then at that moment button should be enabled. please help

FID is the id of textfield and txtHint is div id of textfield

insert is the id for the button

```
  $(document).ready(function()
 {
   $("#FID").blur(function()
 {
    //$("#insert").attr("disabled",false);

  var rollno = $(this).val();

      $.ajax({

     type : 'POST',
      url : 'ajaxpage.php',
    data : $(this).serialize(),
     success : function(data)
   {
    $("#txtHint").html(data);   

    }

    }); }); });
```

ajaxpage.php

```
      <?php
       require_once 'db.php';

          $q=$_POST['FID'];

      $stmt = $DBcon->prepare("SELECT Fid FROM Ftable WHERE Fid LIKE :search ");
          $stmt->bindValue(':search', '' . $q . '%', PDO::PARAM_INT);

           $stmt->execute();     
            $count=$stmt->rowCount();

          if($count>0)
        {
        echo  'notavailable';
        }
         else
       {
          echo  'available';
        }

        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly update you code as per below logic, Which checks if id isnt available then disable your button and enable

```
success : function(data)
   {
        $("#txtHint").html(data);   
        if(data.indexOf("not")!=-1)
        {       
            $("#insert").attr("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $("#insert").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    }
```